# How to set UserID and Password in EnterpriseLibrary 6.0

Tags: enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

I have coded like the below:

### #Code

DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
 database = factory.Create("DBinstanceName");

### ConfigFile Entries

```
<oracleConnectionSettings>
    <add name="CNQ" />
</oracleConnectionSettings>
```

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CNQ" connectionString=" Min Pool Size=0;Connection Lifetime=120;Max Pool Size=50; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST= XXXX.com)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = cnq) (SERVER = DEDICATED) ) );"
        providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

With the above code and config settings, the DatabaseObject is created perfectly.  When I verify the connectionstring it has the values what I had mentioned in the connnection string.  So far good.

Now, I have to add the UserId & Password to the connection string at the runtime.  There is no methods I could find to add the user credentials to the existing connection string.  Becuase, in the Database object the connection string is READ ONLY.

The only way I find is to set in the configuration file[App.config], which is not the way we want, because for every user, we have a separate userid and password in the Oracle database.

In fact, I had tried by settings the connections at the command object, and passed the command object to the execute reader, even then also the enterprise library 6.0, not taking the connection we set in the command object.

Please help us how to set the userid and password in the runtime.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In order to set connection string values at runtime you will have to programmatically create your database objects.  For example:

```cs
Database database = new GenericDatabase(GetConnectionString(), 
    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client"));
```

Or if you are using OracleDatabase something like:

```cs
OracleDatabase database = new OracleDatabase(GetConnectionString());
```

You could use extension methods to hide a bit of the ugliness:

```cs
DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();

Database db = factory.CreateWithConnectionString(GetConnectionString(), 
    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client"));

db = factory.CreateOracleDatabase(GetConnectionString());


public static class DatabaseProviderFactoryExtensions
{
    public static Database CreateWithConnectionString(this DatabaseProviderFactory factory,
        string connectionString,
        DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory)
    {
        return new GenericDatabase(connectionString, dbProviderFactory);
    }

    public static Database CreateOracleDatabase(this DatabaseProviderFactory factory,
        string connectionString)
    {
        return new OracleDatabase(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Another way to approach the issue if you know what connections you will have in advance (still at runtime but perhaps at application startup) is to use the `DatabaseFactory.SetDatabases` method to return the correct database based on a key.  Unfortunately, the method only takes a single string so you can't specify nicely the username and password but you might be able to do something like this:

```cs
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabases(() => GetDatabase("Default"),
    (dbName) => GetDatabase(dbName));

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();               

public Database GetDatabase(string dbName)
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(dbName);
    return new OracleDatabase(connectionString);
}
```

Where the `GetConnectionString` method can create the proper connection string based on a name.  However, I'm guessing this last way might not be the best given your description.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

Because I am using the Enterprise Library 6.0, only the First answer only works.

```
Database database = new GenericDatabase(GetConnectionString(), 
    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client"));
```

[or]

```
Oralce.DataAccess.Client.OralceClientFactory ocf = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory();

Database database = new GenericDatabase(GetConnectionString(), ocf);
```

Thanks